# Rewrite with htaccess not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have a site wich have a dynamic url for 3 pages only. and for that i dont go for php function. So I decided to go for .htaccess rewrite rules but I am not having any luck yet.

This is my actual url: `/index.php?mode=service&inid=1`

I want to rewrite it to this: `/home-theater`

I try it my self and with this code:

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mysite\.com.au$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com.au/$1 [L,R=301]

Options +FollowSymLinks
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.mysite.com.au/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^home-theater/?$ index.php?mode=service&inid=1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

I still can't get it to work.

Also I write index.php to www redirect before this code, so I guess if it cause any issue or not. index.php to www site redirects work perfectly but this is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `L` flag like this:

```
RewriteRule ^home-theater/?$ index.php?mode=service&inid=1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Remember this will not change the URL in the browser since this will internally forward request to your `index.php`.

Also if this doesn't work then provide your full .htaccess in your question.

**Update**: I have modified your .htaccess here, please try it out now after clearing your browser cache:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mysite\.com.au$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com.au/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^ http://www.mysite.com.au/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^home-theater/?$ index.php?mode=service&inid=1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]
```

Comment: thanks for your response but its not working. i need that browser and search engine see home-theater url but server generates page from index url. i think it helps you. i update question and put my whole htaccess code if it helps.

Comment: I have modified your .htaccess in my update section, please try it out now after clearing your browser cache. Also do report relevant sections of your access.log an error.log files.

Comment: Thanks. its work like a charm. i have only one issue now. i have url generate dynamically. with link. so i cant edit url. now what happening. above url works if i write it in browser. but when i go click on actual link it shows old url.

Comment: ok. i shorted it out by myself. i added additional field in db and put values of links and than add it in url. so it generates my url dynamically and htaccess works with that perfect. thanks for your help !!! :-)